# Upgrade Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-upgrading

i am upgrading my contract to a new implementation.
I was wondering if i mistakenly put wrong positions of variables in my new implementation and get my data corrupted, can i upgrade back to original implementation again, and would that fix my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the storage gets messed up because of updating to a contract that has different positioning of old variables, you can easily update your contract again to old version, and no data will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it depends on what you mess up.  If you accidentally change the total supply or some balances, you'll have to change them back.  If you just upgrade to the zero address for instance and don't change anything else, you can just switch back just fine.